# Silverlight, WCF and NotFound, oh my

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I know this is a hot topic on StackOverflow, but do bear with me.

We have a Silverlight 3 application talking to a WCF service. Every now and then, calls to the WCF service return a NotFound exception.

I've read pretty much every post on SO and Google on this subject but I can't figure out what's going wrong. Here are some of my findings:

- The exception happens on random calls and at random moments. Sometimes a method will work for 50 times and suddently it bugs out. I have a feeling it's related to a timeout, since it's most reproducable if I let the application idle for a while before invoking a call, but this is not always the case - sometimes the one of the first calls in the application fails.
- We use the SilverlightFaultBehavior to convert the HTTP error code to 200 and we have plenty of instances where throwing an exception on the serverside actually bubbles up to the client side, so I can confirm this should be working as expected.
- Fiddler shows nothing special at the moment the exception occurs. I don't even see the call in question. This worries me, but it might mean that the exception is a result of a call that happened minutes ago and timed out?
- Service Trace Viewer shows nothing.
- I attach Visual Studio to to Silverlight project and to the WCF services project, set debugging to break on all exceptions (thrown or handled) and it doesn't break (except in Silverlight to tell me about the NotFound problem). This causes me to think that maybe the NotFound is not in response to an exception on the WCF service side?

I really have no idea where to go from here. Any help at all, any pointers or ideas of things to try are welcome.

Comment: Hi, i know it's an old post but i'm having the same issue. Did you get to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts for the points you mentioned:

1) The exception happens on random calls and at random moments - Make sure the data being sent as a return value of method is valid. I had a case when sending an object with some empty properties caused a failure in serialization. I found this out using IIS logs/ Service Trace Logs.

2) So, did you find anything useful?

3) I don't think fiddler can help with this kind of an error.

4) Are you sure about this? Did you set up Trace Logs correctly?

5) You won't find any exceptions that can help you here. The actual exception (when you see 'Not Found' error) is raised while wrapping the message/data from server side or unwrapping message/data on client side.

So, to summarize make sure the data is in correct format (may seem to be correct for you but not WCF, just play with it for a while with different values) and verify the Trace Logging again.

Comment: 2) I mentioned this to avoid people telling me NotFound is just a result of any exception on the serverside. I'm not getting anything useful out of it.
3) I would at least expect to see the call being made to the WCF service, no?
4) To the best of my knowledge, yes. I can see alot of activity going on in these logs - just nothing that seems relevant to my problem.
--
What bothers me most is that it's very hard to ensure the data is in a correct format since I don't know which calls are going to fail before they do, and Fiddler is no help in telling what data is being sent over the wire.

Comment: Oh, and the fact that this started happening out of nowhere, apparently. I'm sure me or some of my colleagues have made modifications, but it seems to be happening all over the place now. And very randomly so.

Comment: "and Fiddler is no help in telling what data is being sent over the wire" - That's why I said it cannot be of great help in this scenario.

Comment: But it should be, since it's showing the data for all the non-failing  connections. Which makes me think that the failure happens before the connection is being made. Maybe some DNS lookup failure of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

What is a binding of the service? Where is it hosted: IIS or VS Deployment server?
I have seen this problem recently, something was wrong with IIS. It couldn't even open *.svc files.
So here is a plan of activities:

1. Try to open svc file using http address like http://localhost/MyApp/MyService.svc
2. If it opens, write a console application and test the service.
3. If it works, write a silverlight simple application.

I hope this will help.

Comment: In general it all works. The Silverlight app can make 100s of successful and then suddently fail once with that error message. I'm testing with VS dev server, I'm hoping that once I deploy to IIS the problem will go away but even then, it's a nuisance when developing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding

```
minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1"
```

to Web.config. By default it is

```
minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="5"
```

which sometime causes this error.